# PHP will not insert user data into SQL?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have created this for a user registration. I am testing this to be input into the SQL database prior to going further. For some reason, this will not input into my database. Any ideas?

I appreciate your assistance.

```html
<?php
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!empty($uid) || !empty($pwd) || !empty($email)) {

    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "connectg";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "my_connectg";
    
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
    
     $SELECT = "SELECT email From users Where email = ? Limit 1";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into users (uid, pwd, email) values(?, ?, ?)";
     //Prepare statement
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($email);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
     if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $uid, $pwd, $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
     } else {
      echo "Someone already register using this email";
     }
     $stmt->close();
     $conn->close();
    }
} else {
 echo "All field are required";
 die();
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: `ssssii` too many here for what you're querying for. Edit: this as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50091378/1

Comment: all of your answers are in the duplicates

Comment: I corrected to ssi, but I still am having the problem

Comment: wow.......... that was fast. In any case; see the duplicates and you will learn how to debug.

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to debug this for a while. I'll check those out and see if I find my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: welcome. By the way; email would be a string and not an integer. The sequence order does matter. @lunartab